# how do i verify that excel sheet already exist in workbook?

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I want to verify if the excel sheet has already exist in the current workbook.

**Here is the Code:**

```
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook
import xlsxwriter

lst = ['Task', 'Status', 'Created_Date', 'Moved_Date']
value = []

wb = Workbook()

def write_excel(fileName, sheetName, *args):
    ws = wb.add_sheet(sheetName)

    style0 = xlwt.easyxf('font: bold on')
    for col, value in enumerate(lst):
        ws.write(0, col, value, style0)
        ws.col(col).width = 0x0d00 + col
        # for row, value in enumerate():

    wb.save(fileName)

write_excel('sample_xl.xls', 'sheet1', lst)
```

Comment: You need to elaborate a bit more...  Are you getting an error when "sheet1" is already  an existing sheet and you're trying to test for it first?  Also, how do you want to handle that case?

Comment: i want that when I use this function it should not add sheet name again, the function must verify that the sheet name already exists.

Comment: Let me see if I understand...  You want it to create the worksheet if and only if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: BTW, in your current code sample, it's not possible for a duplicate worksheet as you're always creating a new workbook from scratch that's empty.

Comment: yes, i want to add sheet if it doesn't exist, and if it, then data should append to it.

Comment: Please review my answer below.  I suggested using `xlsxwriter` instead of `xlwt` as the later has no way of fetching worksheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the [docs for xlwt](https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) and there seems to only an `add_sheet` with no way of detecting duplicates or fetching existing sheets.  On the other hand, [xlsxwriter docs seems to have a better add_worksheet method](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#workbook-add-worksheet) as it raises an exception on a duplicate (which you could catch and handle).

So, something like this:

```
try:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheetName)
except xlsxwriter.exceptions.DuplicateWorksheetName:
    worksheet = workbook.get_worksheet_by_name(sheetName)
```

It's always helpful to read through the docs for the libraries you're using for answers.